# RGB synthesis in pixels in a computer

Tags: image-processing

A pixel is contained of 3 ranges of RGB color synthesis to add colors into a tiny-square small box, as I learned (correct me if I am wrong). But, through these 3 colors admixture can we create any texture of color to display on the screen? So, for example, with these 3 colors, can we make black, pink, purple, saffron, magenta, and so forth?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model

Comment: While this question is interesting, I think that it is off-topic here. You can find relevant information in many online sources. Possible search topics include RGB and CMYK (the color model commonly used in printing).

Comment: Just wanted to add that printers do exactly that. The client possibly wants to print millions of colors and convential ink printers realize this through mixing just a few colors (although the ink is sprayed onto the paper separately). I can't really imagine an application were your problem wouldn't be solved by a printer.

Comment: Please use appropriate tags.  This question has nothing to do with the C programming language.

Comment: @D.W. Actually to add your own tag you need 15+ reputation points. And, I am new to the community. So, I tried to get close. Btw, I actually like people with competitiveness in their spirit. My name is Vinay Sharma, from India, and I’m age 19. Nice to meet you(again).

Comment: I've edited the tag for you.  This has absolutely nothing to do with C.  Looking further at this question, I see that you've asked three questions.  Please ask only one question per post.  "Can it be applied practically?" is too open-ended to be a good fit here; see our [help/dont-ask].  "can be used to enhance the personal experience of buyers" does not seem to be a question about computer science, and seems to be a matter of opinion.  Neither of those are appropriate here, so I am editing them out.  In the future, please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @D.W. I love you man.